# Failed to pull container images via short reference format

Tags: docker, archlinux, docker-registry

I have a problem downloading container images from a private docker registry.
The registry need no authentication credentials and is only available over the
internal network.

I have configured the registries in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like the example
below. I have replaced the FQDN.

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "registry-mirrors": [
    "https://customer-registry.example.com",
    "https://location-a.dev.example.com:17519",
    "https://location-b.dev.example.com:17519"
  ]
}
```

When I use the short reference format to download the container image
apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1 I get the following error:

```sh
$ docker pull apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1
  Unable to find image 'apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1' locally 
  /usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for
  orbis-u/build-env-go, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login':
  denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

When I use the long reference format docker can pull the image

```sh
$ docker pull customer-registry.example.com/apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1
4.2.1: Pulling from apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1
ac9208207ada: Already exists 
5cf798ece9e5: Already exists 
510bf5361e28: Already exists 
b2f42d2b54d9: Pull complete 
4b8be0bf5345: Pull complete 
311322fb5cb6: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f522ce0974ee41dfc7f16fc44682fee77e57bc056e37b27a4bf4885af3f5c375
Status: Downloaded newer image for customer-registry.example.com/apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1
customer-registry.example.com/apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1
```

The same behavior applies to the other configured docker registries.

I have also tested downloading container images via the registries with podman.
There the download via the short reference works fine.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is because I can't download container
images under Arch using the short notation?

System and docker informations:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux markus-pc 5.5.9-arch1-2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 12 Mar 2020 23:01:33 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Lin
$
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 10
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 10
 Images: 71
 Server Version: 19.03.7-ce
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d76c121f76a5fc8a462dc64594aea72fe18e1178.m
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.5.9-arch1-2
 Operating System: Arch Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.54GiB
 Name: markus-pc
 ID: DKFK:PHVZ:LDGJ:54OG:5VJ5:5XYK:YDZR:DJFR:HZ7B:4HDT:LBEK:7JQ4
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: volkerraschek
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
   https://customer-registry.example.com/
   https://location-a.dev.example.com:17519/
   https://location-b.dev.example.com:17519/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Docker

The default registry is configured to search images on docker hub which is `docker.io`. When you pull any image without domain name it will try to pull from `docker.io`, not from any other registry.

If you want to pull an image from a private registry, then you need to use long reference which is

```
docker pull <YOUR-DOMAIN>/apvxw/build-env-go:4.2.1
```

### In Podman

You can configure multiple registries and podman searches in all registries whichever configured in the config file.

Location of podman configuration file is `/etc/containers/registries.conf.` and you can add the following lines in that which you might have already done.

```
[registries.search]
registries = ['docker.io', 'customer-registry.example.com', 'location-a.dev.example.com:17519', 'location-b.dev.example.com:17519']
```